# Modifying bootstrap styles in Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET MVC5: is this a reasonable approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC 5 project for which I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.

The default appearance of the application is largely determined by bootstrap.css. I wanted to modify some styles for example the default font and the background colour of the navbar.

I am new to bootstrap. Is the following a reasonable approach (I've tried it and it works):

1. Download bootstrap source code and install Node.js and Grunt as described here:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

1. Modify values in variables.less as required.
2. Run grunt dist to update the dist directly in bootstrap
3. Run a command to copy the contents of dist to the appropriate locations in the project source (css to Content, .js to Scripts, fonts to fonts). However I am omitting the .map files.
4. I am leaving jquery as-is since the project already has jquery 2.1.1 installed.

This does seem rather a lot of effort just to update a few styles but it is not too bad once set up. However I might be missing a much simpler way and would be interested to know.

Comment: Isn't it simply a case of creating a custom.css and overriding the styles you want to change? Obviously, making sure you include custom.css after bootstrap.css

Comment: Thanks Alastair; you could do, but it seems to me better to change the base font and colours so that the changes flow through the whole stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

If you're a Visual Studio user and know those tools well, my recommendation would be two-fold:

1. Download and install [WebEssentials](http://vswebessentials.com/). This is created by the same folks that build the web tools in Visual Studio and reflects, for the most part, the direction of the product. It's also a hella-good tool for any web dev (for reasons beyond the intent of this answer).
2. Unless you intend on *frequently* changing the colors, I would likely create a separate project used just for editing the LESS source. This allows you greater performance instead of waiting on the build output/compilation of your custom version of Bootstrap.

WebEssentials takes care of saving out your CSS after you make any changes to any LESS file or its dependencies. This is a bit of heavy-lifting (compute-wise), but it's also crazy handy.

What I do is this:

1. Create a new project
2. Install the LESS source via NuGet (the package is Twitter.Bootstrap.Less)
3. Make changes & save the source; the output will be saved automatically in the project
4. Add the output to my "real" project and update my bundles

For extra ninja points, you might create a NuGet package of your own, hosted internally, so that your MVC project actually takes a dependency on that, streamlining changes through versioning and packages.